# How to resolve SQLCODE -805 in DB2 Express C, Windows 8.1, GnuCOBOL, OpenCOBOL IDE

Tags: ide, db2, windows-8.1, gnucobol

I am trying to work with OpenCOBOL IDE and DB2 Express-C. A very simple program TEST0002.sqb is prep'ed and binded with DB2 creating - TEST0002.bnd and TEST0002.cbl files. Now when I execute the Program in OpenCOBOL IDE, I am getting -805. Following messages are displayed: (also attached)

```
F:\COBOL\bin\TEST0002.exe
CONNECT :)+000000000+1ÿ1208ÿAKADIAN
ÿSAMPLEÿQDB2/NT64ÿ2268ÿ2268ÿ0ÿ1252ÿ0ÿ
SQLCODE: -000000805
SQLCAID: SQLCA
SQLCABC: +000000136
SQLERRML: +0036
SQLERRMC: A Øõ( . CÀ[¸õ( 0X00000000604B4100
SQLERRP: SQLRA14D
SQLSTATE: 51002
SQLWARN:
Hello world: 0 -->THIS SHOULD BE 1 IF SQL WORKED :)
--- error report ---
ERROR occurred :

SQLCODE : -000000805
ERR BUFFER :
ERR BUFFER : SQL0805N Package " A Øõ( . CÀ[¸õ( 0X00000000604B4100"
was not found.
SQLSTATE=51002

Package: A Øõ( . CÀ[¸õ( 0X00000000604B4100
001SQL0805N Package " A Øõ( . CÀ[¸õ( 0X00000000604B4100" was not
found.
SQLSTATE=51002

SQLSTATE 51002: The package corresponding to an SQL statement
execution request
was not found.


--- end error report ---****

Process finished with exit code 98
```

**TEST0002.sqb**

```
   IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
   PROGRAM-ID. TEST0002.
   ENVIRONMENT DIVISION.
   CONFIGURATION SECTION.
  *-----------------------
   INPUT-OUTPUT SECTION.
   DATA DIVISION.
   FILE SECTION.
   WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
   COPY 'sql.cbl'.
   COPY 'sqlenv.cbl'.
        EXEC SQL
             BEGIN DECLARE SECTION
        END-EXEC.
   01 WS-SQL-FETCH   pic X(01) value '0'.
        EXEC SQL
             END DECLARE SECTION
        END-EXEC.
   77 errloc          pic x(80).
             EXEC SQL
                       INCLUDE SQLCA
             END-EXEC.
   PROCEDURE DIVISION.
   MAIN-PROCEDURE.
       EXEC SQL
            CONNECT TO SAMPLE
       END-EXEC.
       if SQLCODE not equal zero
       then
            display 'CONNECT failed with rc ' SQLCODE '+' SQLERRMC
       else display 'CONNECT :)' SQLCODE '+' SQLERRMC
       end-if.
        EXEC SQL
             SELECT '1'
               INTO :WS-SQL-FETCH
               FROM EMPLOYEE
              FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY
        END-EXEC.
       if SQLCODE not equal zero
       then
        DISPLAY 'SQLCODE: ' SQLCODE
        DISPLAY 'SQLCAID: ' SQLCAID
        DISPLAY 'SQLCABC: ' SQLCABC
        DISPLAY 'SQLERRML: ' SQLERRML
        DISPLAY 'SQLERRMC: ' SQLERRMC
        DISPLAY 'SQLERRP: ' SQLERRP
        DISPLAY 'SQLSTATE: ' SQLSTATE
        DISPLAY 'SQLWARN: ' SQLWARN
        DISPLAY "Hello world: " WS-SQL-FETCH
        " -->THIS SHOULD BE 1 IF SQL WORKED :) "

            call 'checkerr' using SQLCA, errloc
       end-if.
        STOP RUN.
   END PROGRAM TEST0002.
```

**PREP, BIND & PACKAGE Info**:

```
db2 => prep F:\COBOL\sqb\TEST0002.sqb target ANSI_COBOL BINDFILE USING F:\COBOL\
bnd\TEST0002.bnd QUALIFIER AKADIAN COLLECTION AKADIAN OUTPUT F:\COBOL\cbl\TEST00
02.cbl VALIDATE BIND

LINE    MESSAGES FOR TEST0002.sqb
------  --------------------------------------------------------------------
        SQL0060W  The "COBOL" precompiler is in progress.
        SQL0091W  Precompilation or binding was ended with "0"
                  errors and "0" warnings.
db2 => bind F:\COBOL\bnd\TEST0002.bnd OWNER AKADIAN QUALIFIER AKADIAN COLLECTION
 AKADIAN EXPLAIN NO VALIDATE BIND

LINE    MESSAGES FOR TEST0002.bnd
------  ----------------------------------------------         -----------------
-----
        SQL0061W  The binder is in progress.
        SQL0091N  Binding was ended with "0" errors and "0" warnings.
db2 => quit
DB20000I  The QUIT command completed successfully.

C:\Windows\system32>db2bfd -b F:\COBOL\bnd\TEST0002.bnd

F:\COBOL\bnd\TEST0002.bnd:  Header Contents

Header Fields:
Field   Value
-----   -----
releaseNum      0x800
Endian  0x4c
numHvars        1
maxSect         1
numStmt         5
optInternalCnt  5
optCount        11
Name                Value
------------------  -----
Isolation Level     Cursor Stability
Creator             "AKADIAN "
Collection          "AKADIAN "
App Name            "TEST0002"
Timestamp           "KAHjVNEg:2016/04/13 21:35:07:10"
Cnulreqd            Yes
Sql Error           No package
Qualifier           "AKADIAN"
Validate            Bind
Date                Default/local
Time                Default/local
```

***COBOL Source after precompilation***: **TEST0002.cbl**

```
   IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
   PROGRAM-ID. TEST0002.
   ENVIRONMENT DIVISION.
   CONFIGURATION SECTION.
   INPUT-OUTPUT SECTION.
   DATA DIVISION.
   FILE SECTION.
   WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
   01  SQLDA-ID pic 9(4) comp-5.
   01  SQLDSIZE pic 9(4) comp-5.
   01  SQL-STMT-ID pic 9(4) comp-5.
   01  SQLVAR-INDEX pic 9(4) comp-5.
   01  SQL-DATA-TYPE pic 9(4) comp-5.
   01  SQL-HOST-VAR-LENGTH pic 9(9) comp-5.
   01  SQL-S-HOST-VAR-LENGTH pic 9(9) comp-5.
   01  SQL-S-LITERAL pic X(258).
   01  SQL-LITERAL1 pic X(130).
   01  SQL-LITERAL2 pic X(130).
   01  SQL-LITERAL3 pic X(130).
   01  SQL-LITERAL4 pic X(130).
   01  SQL-LITERAL5 pic X(130).
   01  SQL-LITERAL6 pic X(130).
   01  SQL-LITERAL7 pic X(130).
   01  SQL-LITERAL8 pic X(130).
   01  SQL-LITERAL9 pic X(130).
   01  SQL-LITERAL10 pic X(130).
   01  SQL-IS-LITERAL pic 9(4) comp-5 value 1.
   01  SQL-IS-INPUT-HVAR pic 9(4) comp-5 value 2.
   01  SQL-CALL-TYPE pic 9(4) comp-5.
   01  SQL-SECTIONUMBER pic 9(4) comp-5.
   01  SQL-INPUT-SQLDA-ID pic 9(4) comp-5.
   01  SQL-OUTPUT-SQLDA-ID pic 9(4) comp-5.
   01  SQLA-PROGRAM-ID.
       05 SQL-PART1 pic 9(4) COMP-5 value 172.
       05 SQL-PART2 pic X(6) value "AEAQAI".
       05 SQL-PART3 pic X(24) value "KAHjVNEg01111 2         ".
       05 SQL-PART4 pic 9(4) COMP-5 value 8.
       05 SQL-PART5 pic X(8) value "AKADIAN ".
       05 SQL-PART6 pic X(120) value LOW-VALUES.
       05 SQL-PART7 pic 9(4) COMP-5 value 8.
       05 SQL-PART8 pic X(8) value "TEST0002".
       05 SQL-PART9 pic X(120) value LOW-VALUES.
   COPY 'sql.cbl'.
   COPY 'sqlenv.cbl'.
   01 WS-SQL-FETCH   pic X(01) value '0'.

   77 errloc          pic x(80).
   COPY 'sqlca.cbl'.
   PROCEDURE DIVISION.
   MAIN-PROCEDURE.
       CALL "sqlgstrt" USING
          BY CONTENT SQLA-PROGRAM-ID
          BY VALUE 0
          BY REFERENCE SQLCA

       MOVE 1 TO SQL-STMT-ID 
       MOVE 1 TO SQLDSIZE 
       MOVE 2 TO SQLDA-ID 

       CALL "sqlgaloc" USING
           BY VALUE SQLDA-ID 
                    SQLDSIZE
                    SQL-STMT-ID
                    0

       MOVE "SAMPLE"
        TO SQL-LITERAL1
       MOVE 6 TO SQL-HOST-VAR-LENGTH
       MOVE 452 TO SQL-DATA-TYPE
       MOVE 0 TO SQLVAR-INDEX
       MOVE 2 TO SQLDA-ID

       CALL "sqlgstlv" USING 
        BY VALUE SQLDA-ID
                 SQLVAR-INDEX
                 SQL-DATA-TYPE
                 SQL-HOST-VAR-LENGTH
        BY REFERENCE SQL-LITERAL1
        BY VALUE 0
                 0

       MOVE 0 TO SQL-OUTPUT-SQLDA-ID 
       MOVE 2 TO SQL-INPUT-SQLDA-ID 
       MOVE 4 TO SQL-SECTIONUMBER 
       MOVE 29 TO SQL-CALL-TYPE 

       CALL "sqlgcall" USING
        BY VALUE SQL-CALL-TYPE 
                 SQL-SECTIONUMBER
                 SQL-INPUT-SQLDA-ID
                 SQL-OUTPUT-SQLDA-ID
                 0

       CALL "sqlgstop" USING
        BY VALUE 0
               .
       if SQLCODE not equal zero
       then
            display 'CONNECT failed with rc ' SQLCODE '+' SQLERRMC
       else display 'CONNECT :)' SQLCODE '+' SQLERRMC
       end-if.

       CALL "sqlgstrt" USING
          BY CONTENT SQLA-PROGRAM-ID
          BY VALUE 0
          BY REFERENCE SQLCA

       MOVE 2 TO SQL-STMT-ID 
       MOVE 1 TO SQLDSIZE 
       MOVE 3 TO SQLDA-ID 

       CALL "sqlgaloc" USING
           BY VALUE SQLDA-ID 
                    SQLDSIZE
                    SQL-STMT-ID
                    0

       MOVE 1 TO SQL-HOST-VAR-LENGTH
       MOVE 452 TO SQL-DATA-TYPE
       MOVE 0 TO SQLVAR-INDEX
       MOVE 3 TO SQLDA-ID

       CALL "sqlgstlv" USING 
        BY VALUE SQLDA-ID
                 SQLVAR-INDEX
                 SQL-DATA-TYPE
                 SQL-HOST-VAR-LENGTH
        BY REFERENCE WS-SQL-FETCH
        BY VALUE 0
                 0

       MOVE 3 TO SQL-OUTPUT-SQLDA-ID 
       MOVE 0 TO SQL-INPUT-SQLDA-ID 
       MOVE 1 TO SQL-SECTIONUMBER 
       MOVE 24 TO SQL-CALL-TYPE 

       CALL "sqlgcall" USING
        BY VALUE SQL-CALL-TYPE 
                 SQL-SECTIONUMBER
                 SQL-INPUT-SQLDA-ID
                 SQL-OUTPUT-SQLDA-ID
                 0

       CALL "sqlgstop" USING
        BY VALUE 0
                .
       if SQLCODE not equal zero
       then
        DISPLAY 'SQLCODE: ' SQLCODE
        DISPLAY 'SQLCAID: ' SQLCAID
        DISPLAY 'SQLCABC: ' SQLCABC
        DISPLAY 'SQLERRML: ' SQLERRML
        DISPLAY 'SQLERRMC: ' SQLERRMC
        DISPLAY 'SQLERRP: ' SQLERRP
        DISPLAY 'SQLSTATE: ' SQLSTATE
        DISPLAY 'SQLWARN: ' SQLWARN
        DISPLAY "Hello world: " WS-SQL-FETCH
        " -->THIS SHOULD BE 1 IF SQL WORKED :) "

            call 'checkerr' using SQLCA, errloc
       end-if.
        STOP RUN.
   END PROGRAM TEST0002.
```

Comment: Following settings in OpenCOBOL IDE resolve the issue: 
Compiler Path: C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenCobolIDE\GnuCOBOL\bin\cobc.exe
(x) Path: C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenCobolIDE\GnuCOBOL\bin
(x) 
(x) 
(x) 
(x)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---

> Below settings did work, CobolDb2 Program with exactly same issue is
>   still getting -805.

---

**In below solution** - what does -"VCVARSHALL path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat" is being set up for?

**There was never a release of M Vis Studio 14, it was 13 and then 15. I have installed latest M Vis Studio 17 and it's installtion does not have any file named 'vcvarsall'**

**Additionally, keeping -** 
(x) Path: C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenCobolIDE\GnuCOBOL\bin
(x) 
(x) 
(x) 
(x) 
i.e. config, copy, include & lib causes the compiler to stop working. Wihtout these even compilation can not be performed.

> ***This issue needs to be researched again.***

**Following settings in OpenCOBOL IDE resolve the issue:**

Go to *Edit --> Preferences -->*
**Compiler Tab**

```
Compiler Path: C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenCobolIDE\GnuCOBOL\bin\cobc.exe
(x) Path: C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenCobolIDE\GnuCOBOL\bin
(x) 
(x) 
(x) 
(x) 
VCVARSHALL path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat
Output directory: F:\COBOL\bin
(x) Copy runtime ddls to output directory
Associated extensions: .cob; .pco; .cbl; .lst
Standard: default
Free format: ( )
Compiler flags: ( ) -static ( ) -debug ( ) -g
( ) -ftrace ( ) -ftraceall -( ) -fdebugging-line
Copybook Paths: C:\Users\Public.ASK\Desktop\cobol_a
Library paths: C:\Program Files\IBM\SQLLIB\lib
Libraries: 
Extra Compiler Flags: -ldb2api
```

**Run Tab**

```
COB_PRE_LOAD: db2agapi
```